How to avoid mismatched background colors during CSS transitions with transparency?
Scenario
I recently made an interesting observation in my CSS that took me a little while to understand exactly what was happening.
For example, consider the following code snippet, in which the parent and child elements receive exactly the same background-color at a given scroll value. Both elements also have the same transition defined for the background property.
As you scroll, notice how the background color of the child elements clearly differs from the background color of the parent element during the transition.


function toggleClassOnScroll() {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const threshold = 40;

  if (scrollPosition > threshold) {
    document.body.classList.add("js-scrolled");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("js-scrolled");
  }
}

toggleClassOnScroll();
window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleClassOnScroll);
:root {
  --scroll-transition: background 1s ease;
  --scroll-background: darkgrey;
}

nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: var(--scroll-transition);
}

.js-scrolled nav {
  background-color: var(--scroll-background);
}

nav a {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: var(--scroll-transition);
}

.js-scrolled nav a {
  background-color: var(--scroll-background);
}

/* setup (visual) */

body {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed var(--scroll-background);
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav a:hover::before,
nav a:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Colors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Transparency</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Transitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>




Please note that in my use case, it is necessary that the child elements also receive the background color because of the mix-blend-mode hover effect on the nav item links.

Findings
I think I have an explanation for this (rendering) behavior of the different background colors during the transition:
Since both background colors have the initial value set to transparent, an alpha channel is introduced, which then technically animates from 0 to 1, resulting in the full color defined on scroll.
So it should be the same as defining the background-color in, e.g., rgb() notation with an initial alpha value of 0 and setting this color with an alpha value of 1 on scroll.
rgb(169 169 169 / 0) -> rgb(169 169 169 / 1)

Because of the overlapping background colors with transparency, we get different colors during the transition.
This can be illustrated with a simple Venn diagram:

Attribution: Amousey, CC0, via Wikimedia Commons
Solution missing
Depending on the defined background-color, transition-duration, and transition-timing-function, I personally find this behavior visually quite disturbing.
I was wondering if there is a way (or a tool) to prevent the visual difference during the transition.
Perhaps there is a mathematical function that can be used to calculate this based on the target color, the animation and the overlapping layer?
Or am I thinking too complicated? Is this situation actually common, and is there a ("simpler") solution?

Please note that in my use case, it is necessary that the child elements also receive the background color. --> you need to give a more accurate example because in the one you gave I don't see why you need the background on the child element

Please explain your design. Why do you need the same background on both the nav bar and the nav items?

Thanks for the feedback! I've updated my question. My design requires a hover effect on nav links, but since mix-blend-mode needs a direct background, it won't work here - the links aren't direct children of the fixed nav bar, which gets the background on scroll. The nav bar needs this background to ensure that the links (and other elements within it on my 'real' website) remain visible on scroll.

You might set background-color of link element on :hover only:


function toggleClassOnScroll() {
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const threshold = 40;

  if (scrollPosition > threshold) {
    document.body.classList.add("js-scrolled");
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("js-scrolled");
  }
}

toggleClassOnScroll();
window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleClassOnScroll);
:root {
  --scroll-transition: background 1s ease;
  --scroll-background: darkgrey;
}

nav {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: var(--scroll-transition);
}

.js-scrolled nav {
  background-color: var(--scroll-background);
}

.js-scrolled nav a:hover,
.js-scrolled nav a:focus {
  background-color: var(--scroll-background);
}

/* setup (visual) */

body {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed var(--scroll-background);
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav a:hover::before,
nav a:focus::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Colors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Transparency</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Transitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



Also I think your code is a bit excessive, but probably there's a reason for that.

Thank you for taking the time to help! I was so wrapped up in the transparency problem that I didn't even think of this simple solution... I have simplified the example as much as possible, so it may look over the top without more context. However, your suggestion solves the problem and also allows for further transitions on the backgrounds of the nav item links on hover/focus. Thanks again :)
